# what is @IonicPage decorator in ts.file ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

What is the meaning of `@IonicPage()` decorator which is in ts.file ionic 3 and how to use this `@IonicPage()` decorator

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very important to use the **@IonicPage()** decorator to *lazy load* your pages. By using **Lazy Loading** you make your project navigation lighter, because the pages will only be loaded when needed.
For example, normally you would import a page in your app.module.ts so you could use it throughout the project.

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
```

With lazy loading you'll only need to refer the page as a string while navigating, like this:

```
this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
```

Or directly in the html file like this:

```
<button ion-button navPush="HomePage">
```

In the end of it all you won't need to import pages anymore.

Remember that the page must have the **module.ts** so the lazy load could work.

You can understand better with this [article](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).